# Removing <ul> <li> tag in validation-summary-errors

Tags: css

I have this site that the error message is on this format

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
    <span>Password change was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.</span>
    <ul>
        <li>The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to override the class "validation-summary-errors" to get rid of the 'ul' 'li' to have if line in the above error message inside the "span" tag.  So I have the following code as shown below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .validation-summary-errors li { 
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px -10px 5px 0px;
    }
</style>
```

But the code above seems not working.  How to fix this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply `list-style` property on `ul` not `li`. So try something like this

```
.validation-summary-errors ul { 
        list-style: none;
        margin-left:-40px
    }
```

Comment: have you checked that whether these properties are applying or not ? (using developer console in browser)

Comment: It works now.... I simply have this code... .validation-summary-errors li { 
        margin-left: -40px;
    }

Comment: I would be careful about explicitly setting magin-left:-40px because different browsers will apply different amount. You should really use a reset stylesheet or inline the element

Answer (score 6):

You want to make the `span` and `ul`/`li` messages inline?

Try the following:

```
.validation-summary-errors ul, .validation-summary-errors li { 
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}
```